# Protection for Solid State Relay.. Advice please

Tags: solid-state-relay

Please excuse me if this question is not appropriate for this site..
I wish to switch a Pool Pump using a Solid State Relay.. The pump is rated at 10Amps, 240 Volts AC.
Allowing for a safety margin, I intend to use a SSR rated at 20Amps...
My question is....Do I need to include additional components to protect the SSR from spurious inductive feedback from the motor.. Given the cost of high current SSRs, I consider it important to seek advice before proceeding!
Thank you...

Comment: What's the datasheet for the part you are buying recommend? Maybe the protection is built in already.

Answer (score 1):

The most significant problem with starting motors is the high inrush current when they are first turned on and only dropping to rated current when the motor reaches full speed. Rather than estimating the needed safety factor yourself, you should buy a relay that is rated for starting a 240 volt motor with the power rating of your motor. A solid state motor starter would be better and include overload protection for the motor.